# how to echo table in php by mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to show the table but isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT id menu_id menu_title FROM tbl_menu";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['menu_title'];echo 'test';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks, using MYSQLi know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT id, menu_id, menu_title FROM tbl_menu";
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are connecting to anything. You also need to separate column names by commas:

```
SELECT id, menu_id, menu_title FROM tbl_menu
```

Here's a `mysqli_` example from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, menu_id, menu_title FROM tbl_menu";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row[menu_id];
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT id menu_id menu_title FROM tbl_menu";
```

Must Be

```
$query = "SELECT id, menu_id, menu_title FROM tbl_menu";
```

Your SQL have a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT id, menu_id, menu_title FROM tbl_menu";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['menu_title'];
    }
}
```

To note:

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns a number-indexed array

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns a string-indexed array (indices are names of your fields)

And please, stop using mysql, it is deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) instead.